# Backbone.js trigger event blocks the subsequent statement

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

```js
 obj1.listen(obj2, 'save', function(t) {
   t.preventDefault()
 })
 obj2 = {
   save: function save(a) {

     var saveOrNot = !1;
     this.trigger("save", {
       preventDefault: function() {
         saveOrNot = !0
       }
     });

     console.log("prevent default after")
     if (!saveOrNot) {
       console.log("got excuted")
     }

   }
 }
```

In my opinion, the line after the trigger line always gets executed because the `preventDefault()` doesn't get executed immediately. 
But the "got executed" message does not print. Does the code hang when triggering an event?

Comment: Why do you use `!1` instead of false..?!

Comment: You say this gets printed, that doesn't etc. The code you shared has syntax errors and isn't runnable. What is `listen`..? What type of backbone objects are these..? Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not executed because each time when you run the `preventDefault` function you set the `saveOrNot` value to `true`, but when you check for this value condition it's always false, hence the console log is never executed.

```
if (!saveOrNot) { // this is the line in scope => this is always false
    console.log("got excuted")
}
```

If you want to change the value condition to it's opposite state it's better to use negation:

```
saveOrNot = !saveOrNot;
```

I would rewrite your code in the below manner:

```
obj1.listen(obj2, 'save', function(t) {
   t.preventDefault()
 })
 obj2 = {
   save: function save(a) {

     var saveOrNot = 0;
     this.trigger("save", {
       preventDefault: function() {
         saveOrNot = !saveOrNot;
       }
     });

     console.log("prevent default after")
     if (!saveOrNot) {
       console.log("got excuted")
     }

   }
 }
```

Comment: Honestly, you may not got what i am confused.  The trigger and listen  mechanism is asynchronous ？

Comment: You trigger an event and listen for an event. Why should be asynchronous?